# Erro para acessar método classe pai

Tags: python

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/udemypy/Basico/classes/heranca/ex2/funcionario.py", line 20, in
>   
>       print(gF.getBonificacao())   File "C:/udemypy/Basico/classes/heranca/ex2/funcionario.py", line 16, in
>   getBonificacao
>       return super().getBonificacao + 1000 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'getBonificacao'

```
class Funcionario:

    def __init__(self, nome, salario, cpf):
        self.nome = nome
        self.salario = salario
        self.cpf = cpf

   def getBonificacao(self):
            return self.salario * 0.10


class Gerente(Funcionario):

    def getBonificacao(self):
        return super().getBonificacao + 1000


gF = Gerente("weliton", 312.22, "332322333")
print(gF.getBonificacao())
```

Comment: Se a indentação está conforme você postou, você definiu a função `getBonificacao` dentro do método `__init__` e não como método da classe. Remova um nível de indentação desta função. Aproveitando, na classe `Gerente` você também não fez a chamada do método, faltou os parenteses ali. Se forem esses os erros, acredito que a pergunta possa ser fechada por erro de digitação.

Comment: Está errado mesmo a indentação

Comment: Então agora só falta fazer a chamada do método, como indicado no final do comentário anterior, certo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro, indentação é tudo em um código Python. Um espaço em branco errado e seu código não funcionará: dará erro ou gerará algum resultado inesperado. Na classe `Funcionario` você começa utilizando uma indentação de 4 espaços em branco, então deve manter a constância pelo resto do programa. Para definir o método `getBonificacao` você utilizou apenas 3 espaços e no corpo do método você utilizou 8 espaços. Seja coerente: use sempre 4 espaços.

```
class Funcionario:

    def __init__(self, nome, salario, cpf):
        self.nome = nome
        self.salario = salario
        self.cpf = cpf

    def getBonificacao(self):
        return self.salario * 0.10
```

Já na classe `Gerente`, no corpo do método `getBonificacao`, você não fez a chamada do mesmo método da classe pai, mas sim tentou somar em 1000 a referência a este método. Isto parece não fazer sentido e, para chamar devidamente o método será necessário adicionar os parenteses.

```
class Gerente(Funcionario):

    def getBonificacao(self):
        return super().getBonificacao() + 1000
```

Desta forma, ao rodar o programa, irá ter o resultado `1031.222`, que refere-se ao salário definido no construtor multiplicado por `0.10` e somado em `1000`.

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/FcpZck).

Comment: o meu problema ainda é indentação mas com calma vou corrigindo esses pequenos erros Obrigado pela ajuda